# Oracle check variable type

Tags: oracle

A very quick question

I have a read-only access to Oracle database. However, I would like to check the variable type list e.g.

```
Var1 Varchar(30)
Var2 Numeric
```

etc...

What is the best code to do this?

Thanks

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. No output is produced....

Comment: What do you mean with "variable type list"? Which variables are you talking about? Those from a stored procedure? A package? The columns of a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to view the data types for the columns of a table. If so:

```
select
  column_id,
  table_name,
  column_name,
  decode(data_type,
    'NUMBER',   'NUMBER('||data_precision||decode(data_scale,0,null,','||data_scale)||')',
    'VARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR2('||data_length||')',
    'DATE',     'DATE',
    data_type||'('||data_length||')'
  ) type,
  decode(nullable,'N','NOT NULL') n
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
order by 1
```

If the table resides in another schema, use instead:

```
...
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME' and owner='CORRECT_USERNAME'
```

Comment: If he only has read-only access then presumably the tables reside in another schema, so perhaps he would have more luck with `all_tab_columns`.

Comment: good point, added that to my answer. (the read-onlyness could be on several levels: user, table, tablespace, entire database or maybe some homegrown trigger based enforcement)